# Whenever printing a shape with the opposite decimal separator, the print goes crazy

Tags: c#

I am having an issue with a program I wrote. What it does is it asks for the radius of a circle, and then calculates the circle's diameter and also prints the approximate shape according to given information (it prints as a diamond, but that is not what matters).

Now, whenever I enter a number a radius like 5.55 or 6.66, it prints to hundreds of pages. When I use 5,55 or 6,66 it prints just fine, because it is my decimal separator.

How can I make it so in my code, that when I enter a number no matter with what separator, it displays the radius and diameter etc with a comma?

So if I ought to enter the radius as 5.55, the program shows that the input was 5,55.

I have looked every thread regarding this issue, but I am not able to fix this with my code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApplication42
 {
    class Program
    {
       private static void circle()
       {

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the radius of the circle");
        double circle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double circleRadius = 2 * circle;
        Console.WriteLine("Circle's diameter is: " +circleRadius + "");


        double i, k, count = 1;
        count = circle - 1;
        for (k = 1; k <= circle; k++)
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                Console.Write(" ");
            count--;
            for (i = 1; i <= 2 * k - 1; i++)
                Console.Write("$");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        count = 1;
        for (k = 1; k <= circle - 1; k++)
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                Console.Write(" ");
            count++;
            for (i = 1; i <= 2 * (circle - k) - 1; i++)
                Console.Write("$");
            Console.WriteLine();


        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Start:
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.Title = "Shape"; 
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Press number 1 and hit ENTER");
            Console.ResetColor();

            string tehe = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (tehe)

            {
                case "1":
                    circle();
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("No such  option");
                    break;
                case "'":
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                    break;



            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        goto Start;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you want to accept either. You could either tell the user the format you want or use the current locale for wherever the app is being run and then they'd just enter numbers in the format that is natural to them. Trying to accept both will have problems like if I enter 1,234 should that be a decimal between one and two or should that be a whole number in the thousands? You need to either be able to answer that question so that you can code it properly or you need to make the user specify exactly what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to change any commas to decimal points and use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when parsing:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
input = input.Replace(',','.');
double circle = double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The only risk is if someone enters `1,234.56` as an input, which is a valid `double` but would fail in this case.

A safer method would be to specify that numbers should use decimal points and use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` without replacing commas.